# Remoção de caracter aspas dupla "

Tags: c#, .net, string

Tenho um código que faz a leitura de um CSV e salva no banco as informações, porém acabei pegando um CSV "diferente" do que eu estou acostumado de ler. Este CSV vêm com aspas dupla nas informações.

Ex:
"0";"20151109";"171729";"20151101";"20151106";"V3.0";"00";"20151109171729";"000001"

Há uma possibilidade de fazer um `replace`? A função `remove` que eu tentei ele apenas retira as primeiras aspas. (se há uma possibilidade de fazer o *remove* também, eu gostaria de um exemplo, pois não funcionou corretamente aqui). Vou mostrar um pedaço do que é feito.

```
if (Directory.Exists(pasta_tempFisico))
                        {
                            using (sr)
                            {
                                while (!sr.EndOfStream)
                                {
                                    sline = sr.ReadLine();

                                    if (sline.Substring(1, 1) == "0")
                                    {
                                        string[] DadosRPS = sline.Split(';');


                                        dtCriacaoArqHd = DateTime.Parse(DadosRPS[1].Substring(1, 4) + "/" + DadosRPS[1].Substring(5, 2) + "/" + DadosRPS[1].Substring(7, 2) + " " + DadosRPS[2].Substring(1, 2) + ":" + DadosRPS[2].Substring(3, 2) + ":" + DadosRPS[2].Substring(5, 2));
                                        dtInicialHd = DateTime.Parse(DadosRPS[3].Substring(1, 4) + "/" + DadosRPS[3].Substring(5, 2) + "/" + DadosRPS[3].Substring(7, 2));
                                        dtFinalHd = DateTime.Parse(DadosRPS[4].Substring(1, 4) + "/" + DadosRPS[4].Substring(5, 2) + "/" + DadosRPS[4].Substring(7, 2));
                                        VersaoHd = Convert.ToString(DadosRPS[5]);
                                        codIdnRedeHd = Convert.ToInt32(DadosRPS[6]);
                                        numSeqArqHd = Convert.ToInt32(DadosRPS[7]);
                                        numSeqRegArqHd = Convert.ToInt32(DadosRPS[8]);
                                    }
```

Obs: o `sline.Substring(1, 1)` está deste modo apenas por teste, já que na remoção ficaria (0,1) por conta das aspas.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Faça o [`Replace()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.replace?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0#System_String_Replace_System_String_System_String_):

```
texto.Replace("\"", "");
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/String/ReplaceSlash.cs).

Answer (score 0):

Após o split, para cada campo: se o primeiro caractere é aspa dupla, remova-o; depois, se o último caractere é aspa dupla, remova-o. Faça uma função tira_aspas() para isso, só para evitar duplicação de código.

Comment: poderia demonstrar um exemplo de código? Só para tornar mais claro até para outros que tenham a mesma dúvida, caso sua solução seja útil para terceiros. Agradeço desde já! :)